# How to use Global Variable in Python

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

I'm trying to write a simple code that uses a global variable. I'm getting the following error

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

```
global x

def update():    
    x = x + 1

x = 0
update()
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error occurred because in the function `update`, you are trying to edit a variable (`x`) that is not defined, at least not locally.
The `global` keyword should be inside the function, and hence tell that the `x` you are speaking about is the one defined outside of the function (therefore globally defined) :

```
def update():
    global x
    x = x + 1

x = 0
update()
print(x)
```

This would output 1, as expected.

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4693385/4642859) well detailed answer regarding the use of the `global` keyword.

Comment: @Atinesh edited my answer to add additional informations, tell me if it remains unclear.